# Client side validation not working with ASP.Net MVC Razor and Ajax form

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am displaying a partial view inside a JQuery UI dialog.  The partial view contains fields that include Html.ValidationMessageFor entries and the form itself has a Html.ValidationSummary.  I can't seem to get client side validation to work at all.  I am expecting to see error messages if I leave a field empty and tab to another field.  I have been able to see the validation messages if I include this line upon successful loading of the partial view...

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#theForm');
```

but that is only when I submit the ajax form, not before.

jquery to load the partial view in a jquery ui dialog...

```
$('#theForm').load('/Company/Edit', function (response, status, xhr)
        {
            if (status != "success")
                $('#theForm').html('failed to load details')
            else {
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#theForm');
                $('#theForm').dialog({ title: title, show: 'blind', hide: 'blind', width: '1000px' });
                $('#theForm').dialog('open');
            }
          });
```

Partial View...

```
    @model CompanyDetails

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Company", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod="Post", OnSuccess="closeForm" }, new {@id = "companyDetailsForm"}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary() 
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Company Details Form</legend>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Name)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Name)
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                </li>
            </ol>
        </fieldset>
}
```

Here is the model clas....

```
public class CompanyDetails
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this in my web.config...

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
```

I have the following javascript files included..

- jquery-ui-1.9.2.js
- jquery.unobstrusive-ajax.js
- jquery.validate.js
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

Can anyone spot what I have done wrong?

Comment: Where is `#theForm` element in your markup?

Comment: #theForm is an empty <div> in the view for the main page.  A button on this main page calls the load function to load the partial view into this div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but that is only when I submit the ajax form, not before.

That's how unobtrusive javascript validation works. If you leave a field blank and tab out from it, validation won't trigger until you attempt to submit the form.

Comment: Ah, sorry seems I have misunderstood how it works.  Is there a similar way of achieving the validation client-side, without submitting the form?

Comment: I think this is by design in the jQuery.validate plugin. It would be ubber annoying to a user who is getting validation errors every time he is tabbing out from a field if he left this field blank. This only happens if he has never yet attempted to submit the form. Once he does that client side validation will kick in.

Comment: I have a very similar setup, but in my case validations do not fire at all. I am going to try adding this line then   $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#theForm');